# Is there an online service where I can find a web3 cli?

Tags: web3js, cli

I need this when i`m on a new machine or my node messed up and needs a resync. I know that I`d to trust the service as the source of truth but I only need to do some quick queries.

Comment: I think Infura (https://Infura.io ) is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found what I wanted: at the moment of this writing infura.io will provide you with an endpoint (once you register) which can be plugged into web3 via its constructor.